# Clone azure SQL elastic database to non-elastic server in a different resource group

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I'm trying to clone an existing Azure SQL DB that's in an elastic pool to a standard SQL server in a different resource group.  Whenever I run (with Az Powershell)
`Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromPointInTimeBackup -PointInTime (Get-Date) -ResourceGroupName $TargetRGName -ServerName $TargetServerName -TargetDatabaseName $TargetDBName -ResourceId $Database.ResourceID`,

I get the error `Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'An unexpected error occured while processing the request.`

Comment: Have you tried it  using Portal?

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to copy an elastic pool database to a normal database. And they are on different servers. Is that right?

Comment: @JimXu That is correct, although I'm open to copying an elastic pool database to another elastic pool server, but in both cases, I think the issue is because I'm copying to a different server and resource group

Comment: @LeonYue I have, and it won't let me restore an elastic database's point in time to a non-elastic server, but even if it did, I'm trying to do it all through Powershell so I can automate the creation of environments

Comment: I'm able to do it from the portal by unfortunately I am still not able to do it with powershell (using geobackup). In my case I need to restore from an elastic pool to a non-elastic pool server... Do you maybe know why ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my script, you use Point-in-time restoration to restore your database. But we can not use the way to restore a database on the different servers. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#point-in-time-restore.
[image]

So if you want to restore the database on the different server, I suggest you use geo-store. If we use it, we can restore a SQL database on any server in any Azure region from the most recent geo-replicated backups. For further information, you read the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#geo-restore). Regarding how to implement it by powershell, please refer to the following script

```
Connect-AzAccount
# get geo backup
$GeoBackup = Get-AzSqlDatabaseGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database01"
#restore database
Restore-AzSqlDatabase -FromGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName "TargetResourceGroup" -ServerName "TargetServer" -TargetDatabaseName "RestoredDatabase" -ResourceId $GeoBackup.ResourceID -Edition "Standard" -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S2"
```